# Listing empty column indices from a tab delimited text/csv file using split in python

Tags: python, file, split

I have a csv file with 5 columns and three rows. The columns are tab delimited and the rows are separated by new lines. Some of the elements are empty. I have to find the columns which are empty for all rows. The file is here:

[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bafq.png)

My code is given below. The problem is that it does not work for the last column i.e. if the last column is empty, or there is no value in the last column after the last tab in the line, it is still counted as a non empty string. I have checked the length of "eachElement" and strangely the length shows 1 for 1st and 2nd row, but shows empty string for the 3rd row. Seems like it counts the new line after the last tab in the last column for the first two rows (hence length 1), but logically it should not because I used "for line in content". So each line should contain only that line without the "\n"

```
import sys
import array

rowIndex = -1
countEmptyCol = array.array('i',(0 for i in range(0,5)))    #this creates an unsigned int array of 58 elements and assigns 0 for each
listEmptyColumns = []   #contains index of columns that are empty for all records

#Get number of empty values for each columns in the array
with open("D:\TU Ilmenau\L1T2\Labs\DDM\Python\database.csv", "r", 1) as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    for line in content:
        rowIndex += 1
        colIndex = -1
        for eachElement in line.split("\t"):
            colIndex += 1
            if not eachElement:
                #increases the value of index by 1
                countEmptyCol.insert(colIndex, countEmptyCol.pop(colIndex) + 1)

numOfRows = rowIndex + 1

#Compare if number of empty values for each column is equal to the number of total rows
for idx, val in enumerate(countEmptyCol):
    if val == numOfRows:
        listEmptyColumns.append(idx)
print listEmptyColumns
```

Comment: You should really use a csv parser like `csv.reader()` - https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Why do you assume it is without `'\n'` (hint: it does include the `'\n'`)? Note: you can do `for line in file:` without `readlines()`. If this is not homework then you could look to use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which would make this problem a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

The `line` includes a newline `\n` at the end. Get rid of it in your `for` loop:

```
for line in content:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    rowIndex += 1
    colIndex = -1
    ...
```

I tried this out and it works.